# Typehead in bootstrap not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I can't figure out what is wrong in the below code. it's not showing me the dropdown if I type any alphabet. I would be really thankful if someone can throw some light on this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Bootstrap typeahead example by w3resource</title>
    <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="well">
<input type="text" class="span3" style="margin: 0 auto;" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" data-source="["Ahmedabad","Akola","Asansol","Aurangabad","Bangaluru","Baroda","Belgaon","Berhumpur","Calicut","Chennai","Chapra","Cherapunji"]">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: which bootstrap version are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

Try without quotes:

```
data-source=["Ahmedabad","Akola","Asansol","Aurangabad","Bangaluru","Baroda","Belgaon","Berhumpur","Calicut","Chennai","Chapra","Cherapunji"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, the source passed to typeahead is considered as a string here so you need to do a html escape here

```
<input type="text" class="span3" style="margin: 0 auto;" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" data-source="[&quot;Alabama&quot;,&quot;Alaska&quot;,&quot;Arizona&quot;,&quot;Arkansas&quot;,&quot;California&quot;,&quot;Colorado&quot;,&quot;Connecticut&quot;,&quot;Delaware&quot;,&quot;Florida&quot;,&quot;Georgia&quot;,&quot;Hawaii&quot;,&quot;Idaho&quot;,&quot;Illinois&quot;,&quot;Indiana&quot;,&quot;Iowa&quot;,&quot;Kansas&quot;,&quot;Kentucky&quot;,&quot;Louisiana&quot;,&quot;Maine&quot;,&quot;Maryland&quot;,&quot;Massachusetts&quot;,&quot;Michigan&quot;,&quot;Minnesota&quot;,&quot;Mississippi&quot;,&quot;Missouri&quot;,&quot;Montana&quot;,&quot;Nebraska&quot;,&quot;Nevada&quot;,&quot;New Hampshire&quot;,&quot;New Jersey&quot;,&quot;New Mexico&quot;,&quot;New York&quot;,&quot;North Dakota&quot;,&quot;North Carolina&quot;,&quot;Ohio&quot;,&quot;Oklahoma&quot;,&quot;Oregon&quot;,&quot;Pennsylvania&quot;,&quot;Rhode Island&quot;,&quot;South Carolina&quot;,&quot;South Dakota&quot;,&quot;Tennessee&quot;,&quot;Texas&quot;,&quot;Utah&quot;,&quot;Vermont&quot;,&quot;Virginia&quot;,&quot;Washington&quot;,&quot;West Virginia&quot;,&quot;Wisconsin&quot;,&quot;Wyoming&quot;]">
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wqeUn/)